# Syntax Error In Javascript Object Declaration

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have declared an object like this

```
var me = {'alex','moore','baby','you'};
```

without the property names. I just want the elements to be set of strings. But i get error in both chrome dev-tools and firebug.  i have googled but can't find any good answer.

What am i doing wrong?

thanks.

**EDIT**

Thanks for your answers. The reason am asking is that i am reading a book **"Javascript: The Definitive Guide"**. On page 115 of the PDF file, it states that Javascript Objects ::

```
"They can also be used 
   (by ignoring the value part of the string-to-value mapping)
to represent sets of strings."
```

So i was trying to test it but getting errors. It seems the book is wrong that they can be used to represent sets of strings.

Comment: This is not a valid signature in creating an object.. why dont you create an array instead of this..? `['alex','moore','baby','you'];`

Comment: You need it to be an array. `var me = ['alex','moore','baby','you'];`

Comment: if you want it to be an object - assign a value to each key!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want an ordered list of values, then use an array (`[]`), not a plain object (`{}`).

```
var me = ['alex','moore','baby','you'];
```

Objects must have named properties.

```
var me = {
    foo: 'alex',
    bar: 'moore',
    baz: 'baby',
    etc: 'you'
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like what you are looking for is an array

```
var me = ['alex','moore','baby','you'];
```

Objects on the other hand need to have properties defined.

Answer (score 0):

Square brackets

```
var me = ['alex','moore','baby','you'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using array not object.

```
var me = ['alex','moore','baby','you'];
```